# ESP 8266 WiFiManager.h> //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(180);

Tags: esp8266, esp8266wifi

in my cases wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(180); does not wait for 180 sec, But only 60 sec. my router takes about 2 minutes to setup after power outage my esp does not connect to the router until it hard reset.
code is here for your reviews.

```
 #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
 #include <DNSServer.h>
 #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
 #include <WiFiManager.h>

 void setup() {

 Serial.begin(115200);
 WiFiManager wifiManager;


 //******this
 wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(180);

 wifiManager.setTimeout(180);

 if(!wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP")) {
 Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
 delay(3000);
 ESP.reset();
 delay(5000);
 }

 Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

 }

 void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 }
```

Comment: So file an issue on the repo? This seems trivial to work around,

Comment: `setConnectTimeout` is a timeout for the `autoConnect` function, not for connection to WiFI

Comment: ok then `wifiManager.setTimeout(180);` is for what type of time out?

Comment: after this time the WiFiManager stops the SoftAP and returns from the autoConnect function